# Show that $M_X(t) = 2 E \left[ e^{tX} \Phi( aX-t) \right], \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$ iff $X$ is Gaussian

Tags: pr.probability, gaussian, moments

Let $M_X(t)$ denote the moment generating function of a random variable $X$.  Now suppose that the following expression holds: for a given $a>0$
\begin{align}
M_X(t) = 2 E \left[ e^{tX} \Phi( aX-t) \right], \forall t \in \mathbb{R}
\end{align}
where $\Phi$ is cdf of the standard normal.

Can we show that the only random variable that satisfies the above is Gaussian? The forward direction (i.e., evaluating with Gaussian) is not very difficult to show.  However, the backward direction has been challenging.

**Proof of the direct part:**  Choose $X$ to be zero mean Gaussian where variance $\sigma^2$ will be selected a bit later. Then, let $Z$ be standard normal, and note
\begin{align}
2 E \left[ e^{tX} \Phi( aX-t) \right]
&= 2 E \left[ e^{tX}  1_{\{Z \le aX-t\}} \right]\\
&= 2 E \left[ E[ e^{tX}  1_{\{Z \le aX-t\}}|Z] \right]\\
&= 2 E \left[ E \left[ e^{tX}  |Z, \{Z \le aX-t\}\right] P[Z \le aX-t|Z] \right]\\
\end{align}

Now, the following is just the moment generating function of a [truncated Gaussian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution)
\begin{align}
E \left[ e^{tX}  |Z, \{Z \le aX-t\}\right]= e^{\sigma^2\frac{t^2}{2}} \frac{1-\Phi(\frac{Z+t}{a\sigma}-\sigma t)}{1-\Phi(\frac{Z+t}{a\sigma})}
\end{align}
Also note that  $P[Z \le aX-t|Z]=1-\Phi(\frac{Z+t}{a\sigma})$. Therefore, we arrive at
\begin{align}
2 E \left[ e^{tX} \Phi( aX-t) \right]&=2 E \left[ e^{\sigma^2\frac{t^2}{2}} \left(1-\Phi(\frac{Z+t}{a\sigma}-\sigma t) \right)\right]\\
&=2   e^{\sigma^2\frac{t^2}{2}} E \left[ 1-\Phi \left(\frac{Z+t}{a\sigma}-\sigma t\right)\right]\\
&=2   e^{\frac{t^2}{2a}} E \left[1-\Phi ( \frac{Z}{\sqrt{a}}) \right] \text{  choose } \sigma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\\
&=2   e^{\frac{t^2}{2a}} \frac{1}{2} \text{ by symmetry}\\
&=   e^{\frac{t^2}{2a}}
\end{align}

Finally, note that the $X$ with $\sigma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}$ has $M_X(t)= e^{\frac{t^2}{2a}}$

Comment: What is $\Phi$?

Comment: $\Phi$, at least in statistics, is standard notation for the standard normal cumulaive distribution function, so I guess that is!

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu cdf of standard normal. I will add this.

Comment: @Boby Can you please include your proof of the forward direction, or give a reference? Is there a missing term? Where does the condition $a>1$ enter? Obviously the claimed identity fails as $a  \downarrow 0$, and I do not understand it yet  even for $a>1$.

Comment: @Yuval I added the proof of the direct part. I am not very sure about the restriction on $a$. I think we can assume $a>0$.  Initially, I choose this arbitrarily.

Comment: It might be helpful to note that, since $\Phi(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}\,\text{erf}(x/\sqrt{2})$, the identity can be rewritten as $$E\bigl[e^{xt}\text{erf}\bigl((ax-t)/\sqrt{2}\bigr)\bigr]=0.$$ Is the Gaussian the only distribution for which this expectation value vanishes for all $t$?

Comment: @Boby So the original identity is not valid for a standard Gaussian $X$ but for $X/\sqrt{a}$? That explains why it seemed strange before. You really should rewrite it in terms of a standard Gaussian with variance 1.

Comment: $e^{\frac{t^2}{a}}$ should be replaced by $e^{\frac{t^2}{2a}}$ everywhere.

Comment: @IosifPinelis thanks. Corrected.

Comment: @YuvalPeres  It holds for standard Gaussian if $a=1$. I don't really see what you mean here. I changed $a>1$ condition to  $a>0$.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker  Thanks. Nice observations. I will think how to play with it.

Comment: Can one take the logarithm to make the cumulant generating function and somehow show that it terminates?  Even showing that the 3rd cumulant is 0 would be progress.

Comment: I think it may help to know how this problem arose.

Comment: I wonder maybe there is some Stein equation hiding here that would help prove/disprove. Also how about first studying it for t<0 and so inverting the Laplace transform to see what you get. This product almost looks like the result of the convolution theorem for LT.

Comment: Another proof of the direct part: Suppose that $X=Z/s$, where $Z$ is standard normal and $s:=\sqrt a$. Then the identity in question can be rewritten as $g(t):=Ee^{hZ}(2\Phi(t(Z/h-1))-1)=0$ for all real $t$, where $h:=t/s$. Obviously, $g(0)=0$. It is also easy to check that $g'(t)=2Ee^{hZ}(Z/h-1)\varphi(t(Z/h-1))=0$ for all real $t$, where $\varphi:=\Phi'$, the standard formal pdf. So, $g(t)=0$ for all real $t$, and we are done.

Comment: @Boby In the original formulation you did not mention that the variance of $X$ should be adjusted according to $a$.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment.

---

Let me reformulate$^\ast$ the question in the OP as follows: Consider an integrable, non-negative function $p(x)$, which satisfies the identity
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx}\,\text{erf}\,\bigl((x-t)/\sqrt 2\bigr)\,p(x)\,dx\equiv 0,\;\;\forall t\in\mathbb{R}.\qquad\qquad(\ast)$$
Can we then conclude that $p(x)\propto e^{-x^2/2}$ is a Gaussian? In other words, is the measure such that the convolution of exponential and error function vanishes unique?

If $p_0(x)$ is a solution of $(\ast)$, then also $p_b(x)=e^{bx}p_0(x+b)$ is a solution, for any real $b$. The key point to note is that the Gaussian solution has the *unique* property that it is invariant under this transformation. If there exists a non-Gaussian solution, then we have a class of independent solutions formed by linear combinations of $p_b(x)$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

The argument would be complete if this class of solutions can serve as a basis for any $p(x)$, since the identity $(\ast)$ is definitely false in general.

---

<sub>$^\ast$ To reformulate the identity I used that $\Phi(x)=\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}\,\text{erf}(x/\sqrt{2})$. The coefficient $a$ can be set to unity without loss of generality, by rescaling $x$ and $t$. Since the identity is linear in $p(x)$, we need not require that this function is normalized to unity.</sub>

Comment: You are adding the assumption that the law of $X$ has a density, right? Or can you deduce that from the identity?

Comment: I don't think I need that assumption, if $X$ has only a cumulative distribution I can replace $p(x)dx$ by the measure $d\mu(x)$ and then the transformation would read $d\mu_b(x)=e^{bx}d\mu_0(x+b)$.